# ADD Constraints in value of column based on another value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing an sql constraints about values on columns based on other values in other columns for Example:

if Column Replacement Part = 'N/A', the Replacement Company must be = 'N/A' and verse vice .
if type ='obs' the LTB_Date and LTS_Date Must be Not Null and
if type !='obs' the LTB_Date and LTS_Date Must be Null

Comment: You're  looking for computed columns. Please share what did you try so far.

Comment: Or maybe you're just looking for a `CASE` expression when you selecting the data.

Comment: Not Selecting its a constraints when importing data                                  
ALTER TABLE PCN_Table 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
CHECK (CASE WHEN Replacement_Part = 'N/A' THEN Replacement_Company = 'N/A' );

Comment: I don't think you can do that by `CONSTRAINTS` since the case is like that, you may think of using `TRIGGER` instead.

Comment: ok. I will try to use TRIGGER to make it , thanks a lot

Comment: Don't do this in database. This is clearly a business logic, which should be a part of application, written in the programming language of your choice. Database is just a IO device, would you write this kind of logic in printer driver?

Comment: @Fabio I strongly disagree with you. A database is way more than an IO device, and using it as such means you are misusing the tools you have. A database is much more than just a storage. Anyone that tells you otherwise doesn't know what they are talking about.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, true, database now is more than IO device, only because we misused that for many years. Database providers will be more than happy to create more features to keep your business tightly coupled to their product.

Comment: @Fabio the relational model itself is more than just about storage. At the very least, a relational database should enforce data integrity - which is something you can't leave up to the application that uses the data to do. Yes, modern databases allows much more than what the relational model as first described by codd offers, but that is a good thing - just like the fact that SQL Server 2017 provides way more options than the 2000 version.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, agree again, my comment was only about putting business logic to the database, which is the case in OP's question. Database should handle only data related logic. Database should know "How" to store, and not "What" to store

Comment: @Fabio In your last comment you've hit the point spot on. I totally agree. A lot of developers can't (or don't want to) distinguish between business logic and data logic - but clearly you are not one of them. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `CHECK` constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE PCN_Table ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK(
  CASE
    WHEN Replacement_Part = 'N/A' THEN CASE WHEN Replacement_Company = 'N/A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 1
  END=1
  AND
  CASE
    WHEN [type] = 'obs' AND LTB_Date IS NOT NULL AND LTS_Date IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    WHEN [type] <> 'obs' AND LTB_Date IS NULL AND LTS_Date IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END=1
)
```